# Translating a Paragraph does not work using translate.js

Tags: javascript

I'm using [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/).

Short text sentences work but I'm finding that long paragraphs do not nor do elements embedded within elements as you'll see below.

Here's ALL THE CODE:

STEP 1:

the HTML:

```
<div class="company mar-left10">
    <h4 class="trn">Sustainable Global Solutions' Mission</h4>
        <p class="trn">Sustainable Global Solutions mission is to market, build, implement, and operate sustainable business methods throughout the US and worldwide. The end result of our efforts is to provide proven, proprietary, and economically efficient solutions to our food, fuel, and population crises at hand. Additionally our waste-to-energy systems can utilize solid waste gasification for renewable energy generation.</p>
</div>
```

STEP 2:

The JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () {

     var t = {

    //TITLE
    "Sustainable Global Solutions' Mission": {
        en: "Sustainable Global Solutions' Mission",
        sp: "Misión de Sustainable Global Solutions"
    },
    //**THIS SECTION WILL NOT TRANSLATE!**
    "Sustainable Global Solutions mission is to market, build, implement, and operate sustainable business methods throughout the US and worldwide. The end result of our efforts is to provide proven, proprietary, and economically efficient solutions to our food, fuel, and population crises at hand.Additionally our waste-to-energy systems can utilize solid waste gasification for renewable energy generation.": {
        en: "Sustainable Global Solutions mission is to market, build, implement, and operate sustainable business methods throughout the US and worldwide. The end result of our efforts is to provide proven, proprietary, and economically efficient solutions to our food, fuel, and population crises at hand.Additionally our waste-to-energy systems can utilize solid waste gasification for renewable energy generation.",
        sp: "La misión de Sustainable Global Solutions es comercializar, construir, implementar y operar métodos comerciales sostenibles en todo Estados Unidos y en todo el mundo. El resultado final de nuestros esfuerzos es proporcionar soluciones probadas, exclusivas y económicas soluciones eficientes para nuestras crisis de alimentación, combustible y población a la mano.Además, nuestros sistemas de conversión de residuos en energía pueden utilizar la gasificación de residuos sólidos para la generación de energía renovable."
    },
};
var _t = $('body').translate({lang: "en", t: t});
var str = _t.g("translate");
console.log(str);

$(".lang_selector").click(function (ev) {
    var lang = $(this).attr("data-value");
    _t.lang(lang);

    console.log(lang);
    ev.preventDefault();
});

    }
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you everyone

Comment: there are a [buttload](https://github.com/Marak/translate.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com) of [libraries](https://github.com/tinoni/translate.js/) called [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/).. can you specify which one you're talking about?

Comment: http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/

Comment: Yep, that's the one, you hyperlinked under libraries

Comment: I found that the FIRST PERIOD STOPS the translation.  Meaning: This works: "Sustainable Global Solutions mission is to market, build, implement, and operate sustainable business methods throughout the US and worldwide." But the ENTIRE sentence AFTER that first period DOES NOT!  I'm looking into the translate.js for a possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

SIMPLE as MAKING SURE EACH PLACE the text appears it is IDENTICAL.

Sustainable Global Solutions mission is to market, build, implement, and operate sustainable business methods throughout the US and worldwide. The end result of our efforts is to provide proven, proprietary, and economically efficient solutions to our food, fuel, and population crises at hand.Additionally our waste-to-energy systems can utilize solid waste gasification for renewable energy generation.

I made sure that it was so and WALA!

La misión de Sustainable Global Solutions es comercializar, construir, implementar y operar métodos comerciales sostenibles en todo Estados Unidos y en todo el mundo. El resultado final de nuestros esfuerzos es proporcionar soluciones probadas, exclusivas y económicas soluciones eficientes para nuestras crisis de alimentación, combustible y población a la mano.Además, nuestros sistemas de conversión de residuos en energía pueden utilizar la gasificación de residuos sólidos para la generación de energía renovable.

Thank you to I Wrestled a BEAR ONCE for helping me SEE THE LIGHT!